# Django использование get_absolute_url

Tags: django

Django 1.10

имею

```
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(_('ISBN'), max_length=13, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('Book\'s title'), max_length=128)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('books:detail', kwargs={'isbn': self.isbn})

class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    """Show the requested book."""
    template_name = r"books\book_detail.html"
    model = Book
    pk_url_kwarg = 'isbn'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view=views.BookListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<isbn>[\d\-]+)/$', view=views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='detail',),
```

Нужно применить поиск по isbn, а именно url http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/123/ где isbn=123 должен показівать детальную информацию по книге. Но получаю 404. По url http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/1/ книгу находит. Понимаю, что не можу сопоставить isbn и pk.

Добавлял query_pk_and_slug = True, но не работает.

Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `pk_url_kwarg` объявите поля `slug_field` и `slug_url_kwarg`.

Comment: спасибо. помогло